# Error : FRM-41337:Cannot populate the list from record group

Tags: oracle, forms, oracleforms

I have a record group that is using a block item, i.e. `where cust_id = :order.cust_id`

Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

When I query an existing record, I am able to add a new line and enter the condition code i.e. from the populated record group. But when I enter a new order, the list is empty.  I tried to put the code in `when-new-record-instance`, but I get an error

```
select profile profile1, profile profile2 
  from dss.v_unit_conditions
  where cust_id = :order.dsp_cust_id
    and profile_type = 'UC' 
    and active = 'Y'
```

> 41337 - cannot populate list from record group

If I use that in `when-tab-change`, then I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform query, you acquire `:ORDER.DSP_CUST_ID` value so Record Group Query fetches *something*.

On the other hand, when you're entering a new order, I presume that `:ORDER.DSP_CUST_ID` is empty, query doesn't return anything and raises an error.

It means that `:ORDER.DSP_CUST_ID` must be known. In order to make the Record Group Query work, consider creating it dynamically, i.e. when `:ORDER.DSP_CUST_ID` gets its value. As it seems that you're entering it manually, the `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` might be your choice. Have a look at `CREATE_GROUP_FROM_QUERY` (and, possibly, `POPULATE_GROUP_FROM_QUERY`) built-ins. They are described (with examples) in Forms Online Help System.

Comment: Thanks this help a lot